# How to get Hibernate (3.6/4.0) JDBC bind parameters?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

We would like to get a hold of all the parameters that hibernate binds to SQL statments before they are sent to the sql server. Is that possible?

We're using an Interceptor the get the SQL from Hibernate:

```
public class SQLInteceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

     @Override
     public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
         String prepared = super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
         .....
    }
 }
```

But this gives the query without any parameters.

> insert into Order (CreatedDate, sum) values (?, ?)

Hibernate shows the parameters if you turn logging on, so it's in there somewhere

We're are aware of different JDBC drivers that has this feature. But we're not planning on replacing the JTDS drivers.

Comment: What exactly do you need this for, other than logging (since you already know you can see it through logging, I suspect you have some other need for this).

Comment: Maybe this gets you moving in the right direction? http://blog.aptivate.org/2010/11/03/capturing-prepared-statement-parameters/

Comment: We need the queries for the profiler we've implemented. Looks alot like the mini profiler they use here at SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to use [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/)  and do some hacking to the source code to achieve our goal. Not what we were looking for, but it works.